# How where these eigenvectors derived?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Excuse me for the very simple question. But I've been looking at this problem for over an hour and I do not understand how they derived vector $\mathbf{v_{1}}$ from the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & |& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & | &1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &| & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

This matrix results in:
$$
x_{1} = 1
$$
$$
x_{2}+x_{3} = 1
$$

With $\mathbf{v_{1}} $ as:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}

And $\mathbf{v_{2}} $ being:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}

Shouldn't the first vector be $\mathbf{v_{1}} = (1,0,0)^{\mathbf{T}}$ instead? I do not see how they came up with $\mathbf{v_{1}} = (1,0,1)^{\mathbf{T}}$. I left out the rest of the problem which is about finding a generalized eigenvector.

Kind regards,

A confused student

Edit: Thanks to Infinity_hunter I have figured it out! Here is the solution:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & | & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & | & 0
\end{array} \right)
\rightarrow
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x_{1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & x_{2} & x_{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right)
= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right)
\rightarrow
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} + x_{3} \\
0
\end{array} \right)
= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right)
$$

Then taking for $x_{1} =1$,   $ x_{2} = x_{2}$,   $ x_{3} = 1-x_{2}$, which is written as:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array} \right)
+
x_{2}\cdot\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{array} \right)
$$

Comment: Where do you get an eigenvector? I don't see any eigenvector in this problem (okay $\mathbf{v}_{2}$ is an eigenvector but that seems to be irrelevant). These are just two solutions to $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{v}= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Can you explain how your matrix notation works?

Comment: Hi thank you for your comments! I'm sorry I've written it quite poorly...But I've found the solution! I edited my original post so hopefully everything is clear :)

Comment: @wnr12 Your post is still very unclear. You still mention eigenvectors in the title. But it seems instead you are trying to solve the nonhomogeneous equation $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ mentioned above. You still mention $\mathbf{v}_{1}  = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, which **is** an eigenvector, but clearly does not satisfy your equation. Can you 1: Clarify what is the problem you are trying to solve? 2: Take out any extraneous information.

Comment: Your Edit introduces a new error, possibly a typo.  Note that when the first row is used to "reduce" the second row, the subtraction affect the last (constant term/right-hand side) column.  In it present form the Question needs this critical mistake to be corrected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $v_1 = (x_1,x_2,x_3) ^ T$ then note that $x_1 = 1$ , $ x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = 1$ are solutions to the given system of equations and similarly $(1,1,0)$. The vector $(1,0,0)$ does not satisfy the given system of equations as sum of second and third entries is not $1$. You can take any $x_1$ , $x_2$ and $x_3$ such that they satisfy the linear equations.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has solved my problem and I've added the solution to my original post. Best wishes!